# Holomorphic function $|f| \geq 1$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $f:\mathbb{C} \mapsto \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ and that $|f(z)| \geq 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Show $f$ is constant.

The "equal" part of the problem is quite common but i don't know how to prove the inequality. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: both answers from agha and Frunobulax are correct and clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider function $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}$. $g$ is entire function, because $|f(z)|>1$. Next $g$ is bounded, because $|f(z)|>1$, so $|g(z)|=\frac{1}{|f(z)|}<1$. Now using Liouville's Theorem you know that $g(z)$ if constant, so $f(z)$ is constant, too.

Answer (score 2):

Then $\frac1{|f(z)|}$ would be bounded, so by [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29) constant.

(Note that $\frac1{|f(z)|}$ is defined everywhere because $f(z)$ will never be zero.)